# How to prevent back event bubbling form inner iframe from another domain

Tags: dom, dom-events, event-bubbling

I have a page hosted on, say, www.domainX.com. In my page there is an iframe, src attribute of which is set to www.domainY.com (so it's on another domain). There are some links on the page served from www.domainY.com (so they show up in the iframe). When I click one of these links there happens the navigation inside the iframe. Now, when I move the cursor on iframe, right-click and select 'Back' on the appearing menu, it makes a back in the inner iframe. If I do the same thing again, it does a back on the main window, as if I pressed the back button of the browser (or I right-clicked out of the iframe and selected 'Back').

My problem is: I am OK with back navigations in the iframe, but I do not want them to bubble up to the main window. **I can alter the source code of the page on www.domainX.com, but I don't have access to the source code of the page on www.domainY.com** . I tried attaching an 'onback' handler on the iframe element, which stops the event propagation; but it did not work. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What you are describing is the absolutely normal behavior of browsers in this situation, and the user knows that behavior – so why would you want to change it …?

Comment: It's mandated by software requirement specification. Sorry for not being able to disclose the reasons, but I have to change it.